# Get a node by ID with Guava Graph

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, graph-theory, jgraph

I'm looking for a way to retrieve a node using an identifier, using only the Guava library.
I prefer not to use an external HashSet, which I have considered, because my dataset is too big.

I would like a way to index all of my graph nodes using an index, using a String or integer type, and be later able to retrieve my nodes efficiently.

Right now I could iterate over the nodes set of my MutableGraph, and check for object equality, like this :

```
    MutableGraph<CategoryNode> wikiGraph = GraphBuilder.directed().build();
    for (MyNode node : wikiGraph.nodes()) {
        if(node.equals(new MyNode("myStringIndex"))) {
            // object found !
            return node;
        }
    }
```

But this is highly inefficient if the number of nodes gets big.
Is there a built-in solution for indexing graph nodes in Guava or do I need to use another library ?

Comment: Any library would probably also use a HashSet or similar. Go ahead and use it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're after. Would a collection-indexing solution like [CQEngine](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine) or a more memory-efficient set implementation like [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/)'s, [Koloboke](https://koloboke.com/)'s or [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/)' help?

Comment: @jbduncan Yes absolutely. Thanks for your help, I was looking for a built-in Guava solution but this will do the trick.

Comment: If you could post your answer down below, I will accept it as the solution and close the topic

Comment: @Jean-PierreCoffe Done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to index your graph nodes, sadly Guava doesn't have this feature built in. Consider using [CQEngine](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine), which by my understanding allows you to do this for any collection (such as a set of graph nodes).

Alternatively, if you're just looking for a more memory-efficient set implementation, there is a wide range of options including but not limited to [Koloboke](https://koloboke.com/), [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) and [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).